# Unable to affect changes from CSS file

Tags: html, css

Currently my header looks like this:

[image]

which is generated from:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import { Avatar } from "@material-ui/core";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import OutlinedInput from '@mui/material/OutlinedInput';
import logo from "../Static/white_lotus.jpeg"; 
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

import Upload from './Upload';
import "./LogoSearchProfile_Header.css";

function Header() {
  const [inputSearch, setInputSearch] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="header-left">
        <MenuIcon style={{ fontSize: 28 }} className="header-icon" />

      </div>

      <div className="header-middle">
        <OutlinedInput
          onChange={(e) => setInputSearch(e.target.value)}
          value={inputSearch}
          placeholder="Search"
          sx={{ width: '80%',
                height: '100%'
              }}
        />
        <Button 
          variant="outlined" 
          sx={{
            height: '100%'
          }}
        >
          <SearchIcon/>
        </Button>
      </div>

      <div className="header-right">
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary"> 
          Trade
        </Button>
        <Upload />
        <Avatar
          alt="Remy Sharp"
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518806118471-f28b20a1d79d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80"
          className="header-avatar"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

and

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}


.header-left{
  margin-left: 2%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red ;
}



.header-right{
  /* position: absolute; */
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.header-avatar{
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.header-icon{
  color: rgb(34, 32, 32);  
  margin-right: 20px  
}

.header-icon:hover{
  color: rgb(221, 9, 9);
  font-size: 30px !important;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


.header-middle{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
}


.search-icon{
  font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

I am trying to affect change in `header-left`; however, I cannot seem to change anything. Changing the width does not change the width in rendering, changing the background color does not change it unless I put `!important`. I'm wondering why this is, as I don't see anything preventing me from doing so in CSS?

Comment: You need to create a sandbox.

Comment: Can you show us the generated HTML.

Comment: How do you mean? Posted the image and the HTML.